# Why does Venv virtual environment show Scrapy version showing 2.6 when installed version is 2.11

Tags: python, scrapy, python-venv

Using venv, I do not understand why scrapy version is showing 2.6.1 when the version I have asked to be installed is 2.11.

My requirements file only has this:
`Scrapy==2.11.0`

```
(base) peter@Peters % python3 -m venv .venv
(base) peter@Peters % source .venv/bin/activate
(.venv) (base) peter@Peters % pip install -r crawler/requirements.txt
Collecting Scrapy==2.11.0
  Using cached Scrapy-2.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (286 kB)
... more install logs...
```

If I immediately run scrapy version it shows 2.6. But if I activate the env again, it shows it correctly.

```
(.venv) (base) peter@Peters % scrapy version
Scrapy 2.6.1
(.venv) (base) peter@Peters % source .venv/bin/activate
(.venv) (base) peter@Peters % scrapy version
Scrapy 2.11.0
```

Comment: Sounds like it's related to [caching paths to executables to avoid subsequent lookups](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables).